# Create an object based on 2 others

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

I have two objects a and b defined like this:

```
a = { 
  a: 1, 
  af: function() { console.log(this.a) }, 
};
b = { 
  b: 2, 
  bf: function() { console.log(this.b) },
};
```

What I want now is to create another object which will get the properties of a and b, like this:

```
c = { 
  a: 1, 
  af: function() { console.log(this.a) },
  b: 2, 
  bf: function() { console.log(this.b) },
}
```

Note that a and b need to stay the same.

Any idea of how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a for in loop for both a and b, and copy all `hasOwn` properties to a new object.

```
var c = {};
for (var p in a)
    if(a.hasOwnProperty(p))
         c[p] = a[p];
for (var p in b)
    if(b.hasOwnProperty(p))
         c[p] = b[p];
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtvWv/)

---

Or, if you happen to be using jQuery, you could do:

```
var c = $.extend({}, a, b);
```

Comment: The jQuery solution is awesome !

Comment: @NicolasBADIA - yeah, $.extend is great

Answer (score 1):

```javascript
var i, c={};
for (i in a) { if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) { c[i] = a[i]; } }
for (i in b) { if (b.hasOwnProperty(i)) { c[i] = b[i]; } }
```

You can abstract this functionality into your own ["extend" function similar to the one provided by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
function extend() {
  var i, j, x, o=(arguments[0] || {});
  for (i=1; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    x = arguments[i];
    for (j in x) { if (x.hasOwnProperty(j)) { o[j] = x[j]; } }
  }
  return o;
}
var c = extend({}, a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var desc    = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor,
    props   = Object.getOwnPropertyNames,
    define  = Object.defineProperty;

function extend( target ) {
    return {
        with: function( source ) {
            props( source ).forEach(function( key ) {
                define( target, key, desc( source, key ) );
            });
        }
    };
}
```

So now we can go like

```
var c = Object.create( null );

extend( c ).with( a );
extend( c ).with( b );
```

---

<sup>Disclaimer: the provided codes assume we are in a ES5 or ES5 shimed environment !</sup>